# Cairngorm Model Locator Pattern

Tags: apache-flex, design-patterns, cairngorm

In Cairngorm (Flex Framework), there is Model Locator Pattern, which is similar to Global variables, is it a right pattern, Adobe is saying for flex its best pattern

> *Adobe Consulting team conceived the Model Locator pattern as a best
>   practice for Flex developers to adopt.
>   The Model Locator pattern is unique
>   because it is not a pattern we
>   borrowed from the Core J2EE Pattern
>   catalog. Instead, we created this
>   pattern particularly for Flex
>   application development. Our
>   motivation was to have a single place
>   where the application state is held in
>   a Flex application and where view
>   components are able to “locate” the
>   client-side model that they wish to
>   render. Our Model Locator pattern
>   strategy encourages the use of data
>   binding so that view components bind
>   directly to the client-side state held
>   in the single instance of the
>   ModelLocator class. In this way,
>   whenever the model is updated in
>   ModelLocator, all view components
>   binding to the model receive
>   notifications (through the underlying
>   data-binding mechanism) and update
>   themselves to render the new model on
>   the client.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I am reading, I suspect that you are talking about Cairngorm 2 and its advised best practices. You should know that the Cairngorm framework has changed drastically since version 2.

There now is a newer version, [Cairngorm 3](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm) which is more like a set of guidelines, tools and libraries which you can incorporate in a project that is created with any other Flex application framework.

I would advise you to look into some of the new(er) frameworks like [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/), [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) or [Spring ActionScript](http://www.springactionscript.org/)

Cheers

Comment: I just need to know what adobe is telling, that using Global variable pattern is good in some cases?

Comment: Hence the answer. If you have an existing project and really need to use Cairngorm 2, then indeed there is no other way to go. But otherwise I would advise you to use any newer framework since from my experience with cairngorm2, there were some issues with some of the design patterns used. For example Commands that were responders to RPC calls.

Comment: @Sandeep Manne, Actually, the model locator is an [anti-pattern](http://blog.iconara.net/2008/04/13/architectural-atrocities-part-x-cairngorms-model-locator-pattern/) and *should not be used. EVER*.  I've hit a lot of problems with this in the past.  Do listen to Dennis and don't use Cairngorm 2.  Cairngorm 3 are just extensions for Parsley, which I personally recommend for large enterprise applications.  Robotlegs is another very good framework.  **Whatever you do, do not use Cairngorm 2.  You have been forewarned!**